# Elegantly Cloning a git org, with all repos

Tags: bash, git, github, clone, pull

I have been trying to clone the entire github repo for my org to my linuxbox using this one liner (which btw works just fine):

```
for i in `curl -s https://USR:PWD@api.github.com/orgs/ORG/repos?per_page=200 |
          jq .[].ssh_url | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/git@//g' |
          sed 's/github.com:ORG\///g' | sed 's/.git//g' `
do
    echo -e "Starting to Clone : $i" && git clone https://USR:PWD@github.com/ORG/$i
done
```

is there a better more elegant way to do so ? if so please share your experience below as i would like to learn ,

Thanks 
Cumulonimbus

Comment: You can get rid of the `sed 's/"//g'` by using `jq --raw-output`. I would also recommend using `$(...)` for the subshell instead of the older backticks notation. Looks like there's no good reason for the `-e` flag on the `echo` too. Depending on the input you receive from the curl command, it might be better to merge all the `sed` commands in a single one, you should probably add a sample of such an output since we can't reproduce it without having a github account

Comment: Are you using the wrong terminology here? To clone a *repository* you would execute a single `git clone` command. Are you trying to clone *all* the *repositories* (plural)?

Comment: Thanks @Aaron i will change it ..

Comment: Yes @LasseVågsætherKarlsen im doing a full backup of the entire company repository as in plural repositories under one organization folder

Comment: I believe the `per_page` parameter [only goes up to 100](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination). Your script will fail silently if you end up having more repos than that. If you request `api.github.com/orgs/ORG` it should provide a `public_repos` counter. Possibly `private_repos` too. You could use these to generate the right number of requests by using a suitable `page=#` parameter.

Comment: `... | .jq .[].clone_url | sed "s,//,&${auth}@," | xargs -n1 git clone` could replace the last five lines (or `... | xargs -n1 echo git clone | sh -x` if you need to show the url)